# Godot Engine 3.4.4 source compilation error after editing editor SVGs

Tags: compilation, scons, godot

I compiled the engine successfully without changing anything, but after editing "...\editor\icons\ *.svgs" with inkscape, I got an error.

```
D:\C2\godot-3.4.4-stable\editor\editor_icons.gen.h(375): error C2026: string too big, trailing characters truncated
scons: *** [editor\editor_themes.windows.tools.64.obj] Error 2
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

I just changed colors and I used **svgcleaner** to optimize SVGs, but still, an error occurred.

Can you please tell me where is the problem?

```
System Specification:
Windows 11
Visual Studio 2019
Scons 4.2
Python 3.10.3
InkScape 1.1
Godot version 3.4.4
```

Comment: I'd try reverting the change to all the .svgs and slowly add them back to see if it's one particular svg which is causing the issue?

Comment: This seems to be a compiler error which has nothing to do with SCons. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2026?view=msvc-170 I suggest updating the tags on the question.